# How do I add text over a hyperlink while maintaining "clickability" of the area of the text?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have text over a hyperlink like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="..." NavigateUrl="..." ></asp:HyperLink>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 300px">MyText</div>
```

But the user can't click on the text area. I know I can just make the text a new hyperlink with the same destination URL, but is there a better way - to make the text "transparent to clicks"?

Comment: Could you post the HTML-output of this asp.net line? Is it just like: `<a></a><div></div>`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere They are both contained in a containing div.

Comment: Could you simple change it to this output: `<a>Link Text<div>Content</div></a>`. This is also valid HTML5. So maybe like this (don't know asp): `<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="..." NavigateUrl="..." ><div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 300px">MyText</div></asp:HyperLink>`

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thanks. You can post that as an answer. (It doesn't seem to work in ASP.Net but at least it works in html.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a structure like:

```
<a href="">Link</a>
<div>Content</div>
```

and want to have the `div` to be clickable as well without adding an additional anchor, you can use this:

```
<a href="">
    Link
    <div>
        Content
    </div>
</a>
```

As HTML5 allows block elements within `<a>`-tags this is perfectly valid.

You only have to port it into an asp-statement, 'cause I've never used asp.net. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that comes to mind is to use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/) on the text - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3143980)

```
pointer-events: none;
```

However, this is not yet supported by IE and Opera (well, it is, but only for SVG).